# Запись данных в xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Есть список словарей вида:
`[{"first_name":"Ivan", "last_name":"Ivanov", "city":"Moscow"}, {"first_name":"Sergey", "last_name":"Sidorov", "city":"Sochi"}...]`
Мне нужно этот список записать в xml формат вида:

```
<root>
     <person1>
         <first_name>Ivan</first_name>
         <last_name>Ivanov</last_name>
         <city>Moscow</city>
     </person1>
     <person2>
         ...
     </person2>
     ...
</root>
```

Как это реализовать, используя стандартные библиотеки python?
Вот мой код:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('root')
person = ET.SubElement(root,'person')
a=[]                                  # тот список
for key in a:
    ET.SubElement(person,'first_name').text = key['first_name']
    ET.SubElement(person,'last_name').text = key['last_name']
    ET.SubElement(person,'city').text = key['city']
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('xmlf.xml')
```

Но этот цикл неправильный, выход такой:

```
<root>
     <person>
         <first_name>Ivan</first_name>
         <last_name>Ivanov</last_name>
         <city>Moscow</city>
         <first_name>Sergey</first_name>
         <last_name>Sidorov</last_name>
         <city>Sochi</city>
         ...
     </person>
</root>
```

Как его исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исправил код в вопросе:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

items = [
    {"first_name": "Ivan", "last_name": "Ivanov", "city": "Moscow"},
    {"first_name": "Sergey", "last_name": "Sidorov", "city": "Sochi"},
]

root = ET.Element('root')

for i, item in enumerate(items, 1):
    person = ET.SubElement(root, 'person' + str(i))
    ET.SubElement(person, 'first_name').text = item['first_name']
    ET.SubElement(person, 'last_name').text = item['last_name']
    ET.SubElement(person, 'city').text = item['city']

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('xmlf.xml')
```

Результат (с добавлением отступов):

```xml
<root>
    <person1>
        <first_name>Ivan</first_name>
        <last_name>Ivanov</last_name>
        <city>Moscow</city>
    </person1>
    <person2>
        <first_name>Sergey</first_name>
        <last_name>Sidorov</last_name>
        <city>Sochi</city>
    </person2>
</root>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, такого в стандартной библиотеке нет, но такое реализовано в библиотеке [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict#roundtripping):

```
# pip install xmltodict
import xmltodict

my_dict = {
    'response': {
        'status': 'good',
        'last_updated': '2014-02-16T23:10:12Z',
    }
}
print(xmltodict.unparse(my_dict))
```

Консоль:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response><status>good</status><last_updated>2014-02-16T23:10:12Z</last_updated></response>
```

---

Чтобы получить результат как в вопросе, понадобилось [привести словарь в нужный формат](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d3d2411d34e282c074d0285854d3d78b656f28da/XML_to_dict__xmltodict__examples/dict_to_xml__unparse__real_example.py):

```
my_dict = {
    'root': {
        'person1': {"first_name": "Ivan", "last_name": "Ivanov", "city": "Moscow"},
        'person2': {"first_name": "Sergey", "last_name": "Sidorov", "city": "Sochi"},
    }
}

# Параметр full_document=False убирает из XML строку "<?xml version="1.0 ..."
print(xmltodict.unparse(my_dict, pretty=True, full_document=False))
```

Консоль:

```xml
<root>
    <person1>
        <first_name>Ivan</first_name>
        <last_name>Ivanov</last_name>
        <city>Moscow</city>
    </person1>
    <person2>
        <first_name>Sergey</first_name>
        <last_name>Sidorov</last_name>
        <city>Sochi</city>
    </person2>
</root>
```